# titlesec section font size incorrect

Tags: sectioning, formatting, titlesec

My dissertation requires the section title to be of the same font size as the text. I am using the `titlesec` package and I have provided these options:

```
\usepackage[rm,tiny,center,compact]{titlesec}
```

I have also provided formats for the headings such as

```
\titleformat{\chapter}{\centering\normalsize}{\thechapter.}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\it}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
```

All the headings, like the subsection headings work fine, they have the same font size as the paragraph text in the document. The section headings however, are larger by default. No matter what formatting specifications I provide in

```
\titleformat{\section}{..........}{\thesection}{1em}{}
```

the section headings remain large. Kindly let me know what else I can do to fix this.

As requested, here is a list of the packages I am using

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1.25in,bmargin=1.25in,lmargin=1.4in,rmargin=1.15in}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[rm,tiny,center,compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{graphicx,float,wrapfig}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tocvsec2}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{tamuconfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{mycommands1}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\allowdisplaybreaks[2]
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain} % No headers, just page numbers
\pagenumbering{arabic} % Arabic numerals
\setcounter{page}{1}
\chapter{\uppercase{Chapter heading ABC }} \label{chap: introduction}
\section{Section title Abcdefgh}
\subsection{Subsection title Abcdefgh}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection title Abcdefgh}
Paragraph text size Abcdefgh. \\
Paragraph text in bold for comparison \textbf{Abcdefgh}
\end{document}
```

And here are the details of the `tamuconfig` package where the headings are formatted:

```
\ProvidesPackage{tamuconfig}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%   Titlesec Customations 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\titleformat{\chapter}{\centering\normalsize}{\thechapter.}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\it}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchapleader}
    {\protect\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}}  % puts leader dots on chapters.
```

The resulting pdf shows the section headings as in the attached image (unable to upload as I am a new user). As you can see, all the headings work fine, except for the section heading, which is large.
Kindly let me know if this information is enough

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it), or press Ctrl + K.

Comment: Please try to complete your code snippet to a *complete*, minimal document illustrating the problem. I ask you this because some tests with the snippets you gave, produced the expected result so something else must be going on in your actual document.

Comment: Sorry, but with the new addition the problem still cannot be reproduced; as I asked you before, please add enough code as to allow us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Not only *complete* (i.e., what is `\usepackage{mycommands1}` doing there?), but also *minimal* (i.e., surely you can reproduce the problem without loading all of these packages).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example compiles and gives no errors (other than `mycommands1` being unknown) and gives the correct and desired results. So the most likely cause is that this private package contains some redefinition of `\section` that overwrites the earlier settings, or perhaps loads some more packages that do this. So check what is in there (or disable it for a test).

Comment: In the process of trying to create a minimum example, I figured out the problem.  As you had predicted, there was a redefinition at a later stage that was creating the change in section font size. Sorry for the trouble, and thank you for your time.